# Is there any way to show live code demos in your presentation?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, powerpoint, livecode

Is there any way to show live HTML/CSS code demos in PowerPoint? or any other recommended way to teach HTML to high school students

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by **show live HTML/CSS** but if you want to run the code then you need a browser to run it. so you create your project and files and run it on the browser and show it, you can't run the code in PowerPoint.

Comment: run code inside powerPoint

Answer (score 1):

There are two Extensions called "**Live Server**" and "**Live Preview**" which could help...

Comment: These Extensions only work in VSCode, i need to demo code in my ppt, without opening VSCode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).